# Python - Nested Dictionary - Extracting Values

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

The below nested dictionary stores the number of olympic medals that have been won by various countries in different cities (Beijing,London,Rio). The below code also calculates the number of medals that USA has won. Is there a more Pythonic, clean or efficient way to get that list?

```
nested_d = {'Beijing':{'China':51, 'USA':36, 'Russia':22, 'Great Britain':19}, 'London':   {'USA':46, 'China':38, 'Great Britain':29, 'Russia':22}, 'Rio':{'USA':35, 'Great Britain':22, 'China':20, 'Germany':13}}

bei=nested_d["Beijing"]["USA"]
lon=nested_d["London"]["USA"]
rio=nested_d["Rio"]["USA"]

US_count.append(bei)
US_count.append(lon)
US_count.append(rio)
print(US_count)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Index the dictionaries which are the values of `nested_d` (you don't care about the keys here):

```
nested_d = {'Beijing':{'China':51, 'USA':36, 'Russia':22, 'Great Britain':19},
            'London': {'USA':46, 'China':38, 'Great Britain':29, 'Russia':22},
            'Rio':{'USA':35, 'Great Britain':22, 'China':20, 'Germany':13}}

US_count = sum(v['USA'] for v in nested_d.values())

print(US_count)
```

gives:

```
117
```

If you want to allow for the possibility that USA is not listed in one or more of the dictionaries, then use:

```
US_count = sum(v.get('USA', 0) for v in nested_d.values())
```

This will avoid a potential `KeyError`, by supplying a default value.  (Try it with `'Germany'` instead of `'USA'` to see this.)

Answer (score 0):

yes, nifty list comprehension

```py
>>> US_count = sum([nested_d[x]["USA"] for x in nested_d])
>>> US_count
117
```

Edit: `sum` also works with generators so `sum(nested_d[x]["USA"] for x in nested_d)` is equivalent, but imo at the end of the day it's just personal preference and what you're comfortable with.

Comment: I'd lose the outer-most square brackets - `sum` works with generator arguments, and there's no need to force the results to a list.